# Calculate the duration from the table which has logon time and logoff time as different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, duration

I have a table(ADR) with agent login information. It has a row for each time agent is logged on or logged off. An agent can login and log off multiple times a day. EventID =11 means logged on and eventid=21 means logged off. The output required is a single row for every logon and logff with the logon and logoff time and duration. If the first event of the day is logged off that means agent has logged on the previous day and logged off today. So the duration would be calculated from the beginning of the day to the time he logged off. Similarly, If the last event is logged on that day, duration is calculated from that time till the end of that day.

Data:

[image: This is input data from table ADR]

[image: This is the output required]

I tried to use case statement and then select only the rows that are needed. Haven't fully developed the query yet. Posting what I was going to try.

```
select a.AgentID,a.QueueID,case when a.rownum =1 and  a.laststateduration=0 then a.EventTime
                        else when a.rownum =1 and a.laststateduration<>0  then CAST(CAST(a.EventTime as date) as datetime) end as LogonDatetime,
                        case when a.rownum=1 and  a.laststateduration=0 
then a.EventTime ....
from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EventTime asc) as rownum from ADR
where EventID in (11,21)
and convert(date,EventTime) = '2021-02-02'
and AgentID =1006
and QueueID in (6017,6018)) a
```

Comment: @DaleK It was never mentioned that I had to put what I had tried in the guide lines or atleast I didnt know since I'm posting for first time. You could definitely ask me if you want me to make it clear for you. 
Anyway I have updated my post.

Comment: its all here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes much harder if the logins and logout are not fully interleaved.  Assuming they are, I might suggest `lead()` and filtering:

```
select t.*, 
       datediff(second, eventtime, next_eventtime) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lead(eventtime) over (partition by agentid, queueid order by eventtime) as next_eventtime
      from t
      where eventid in (11, 21)
     ) t
where eventid = 11;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this. I didn't get the expected result. But with the lead function i can see how to achieve my result.

Comment: @Krish . . . You can set up a db<>fiddle of some sort.  I'm not sure what your "expected' result is, but this should be doing what you want.

Comment: @GordanLinoff, Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. With your solution I can only achieve last 2 rows but not the first row in my output. But thank you for your answer, I understood lead and lag functions and modified your answer a bit to get what I wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure where to post my answer so I edited yours. Let me know if that is ok. If not, Kindly tell me where I can post my answer

Comment: @Krish . . . If the solution is based on this solution, you should add the a note such as "EDITED by OP" and add your additional comments and codes after that.  You probably shouldn't change the code that is there, other than to fix typos and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it in below manner if environment is suitable for temp table.

```
if object_id('#temp.#Rep') is not null drop table #Rep
Select O.AgentID, O.EventTime as Logon,
(Select Top 1 EventTime from ARD i where i.AgentID = O.AgentID and i.EventTime > o.EventTime and i.EventID=21 Order By i.EventTime) as Logout,
Into #Rep
 from ARD O
where EventID = 11

select r.*,
(case when Logout is not null then datediff(second, Logon, Logout) else 0 end) as DurationSecs
from #Rep r
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter the proposed solution you need to handle cases where people leave without logging off (leave workstation open, crash, plug pulled...), multiple login log off that overlap. So, I would loop through the records and use a small FSA for each user with two states (logged in / logged off) and the state transition caused by a login, logout event, timeout. Along with the event the time information is important (what to do with a lift or timeout that happens after hour.

Unless, you have a perfect system, whatever quick query or whatever won't cut it. I have gone through this a couple of times handling the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I'll keep that in mind. In my case, this is not a problem as the agents will be logged off after a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I built up on the solution by Gorden Linoff. Used if condition to check if the first row is logon/logoff and used **LAG** function with default value to get the logon time and similarly used **LEAD** function with default value to get logoff time. Finally removed duplicates using where condition.

```
select a.*, datediff(second, a.Logon, a.Logoff) as Duration
from (
                select  AgentID, QueueID,eventid, iif(eventid =21, lag(eventtime,1, cast(cast(EventTime as Date) as datetime)) over (partition by convert(date,EventTime),agentid, queueid order by eventtime),
                                    EventTime) as logon , 
                                iif(eventid =11, lead(eventtime,1,DATEADD(Minute, -1,cast(cast(EventTime+1 as Date) as datetime))) over (partition by convert(date,EventTime),agentid, queueid order by eventtime),
                                    EventTime) as Logoff
                from ADR
                where eventid in (11, 21)
        ) a
where a.eventid =11 or (a.eventid =21 and CAST(a.logon as time)='00:00:00.0000000')
```